# Conditional tree vertex rendering?

Tags: plotting, trees

I use the following code to plot a binary tree

```
TreePlot[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 24 -> 30, 24 -> 50, 
  40 -> 55, 40 -> 45}, VertexLabeling -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
     RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
     Text[#2, #1]} &), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The question is what should I do if I want to change the back color of vertex "11" and "23" to red? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, use `TreeGraph` with `VertexShapeFunction` and then `SetProperty[{g, 11}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], Red, Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
     Text[#2, #1]} &)]`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! Do you know how do I change the font size in TreeGraph? TreeGraph seems not to support PlotStyle directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ar = ConstantArray[RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], 55];
ar[[{11, 23}]] = Red;



 TreePlot[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 24 -> 30, 24 -> 50, 
      40 -> 55, 40 -> 45},
     VertexLabeling -> All,
     PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13},
     VertexRenderingFunction -> 
        ({EdgeForm[White], ar[[#2]], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, Text[#2, #1]} &),
     AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach that does the work in `VertexRenderingFunction`:

```
$redDisks = {11, 23};

TreePlot[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 24 -> 30, 24 -> 50, 
  40 -> 55, 40 -> 45}, VertexLabeling -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, VertexRenderingFunction -> 
  ({EdgeForm[White], If[MemberQ[$redDisks, #2], Red, 
     RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255]], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
    Text[#2, #1]} & ), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also post-process the output of `TreePlot` to change the styles of select vertices:

```
ClearAll[modify]
modify = # /. d : Disk[(Alternatives @@ Cases[#, Text[Alternatives @@ #2, p_] :> p, 
 {0, Infinity}]), _] :> {#3, d} &;
```

Examples:

```
tp = TreePlot[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40, 23 -> 39, 24 -> 30, 
    24 -> 50, 40 -> 55, 40 -> 45}, VertexLabeling -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
       RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.2], White, 
       Text[#2, #1]} &), AspectRatio -> Automatic];

modify[tp, {11, 23}, Red]
```

[image]

```
Fold[modify[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, tp, {{{11, 23}, Red}, {{45, 50}, Purple}}]
```

[image]